# Function for Bisection of sides of Polygons

Tags: geometry, functions, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, polygons

Let's say you start out with the side of a hexagon. Then you bisect it to get two sides of a dodecagon. Then you bisect those sides to get four sides of a 24-gon. Then you bisect those to get eight sides of a 48-gon, etc. etc.

Is there a neat function that describes the progression of the values of these sides? Let's say, for example, when you plug in 1 for this function, f(x), it gives you the side of the hexagon. Plug in 2, you get the value of one of the sides of the dodecagons, and plug in 3, you get the value of one of the sides of the 24-gon, etc. etc.

Didn't Gauss find anything like this?

Any info is appreciated!
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bisect" a hexagon to get "two sides of a dodecagon"?

Comment: The value of these sides relies on the fact that the side you are looking for is the base of an isosceles triangle, i.e., $2 \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{3*2^{(n-5)}})$: it works for $n=6$ (hexagon), and then the angle is halved at each step.

Comment: @N.Bach I added a pic in the problem description.